# Implicit type conversion in function pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have 2 classes: `Child` derives from `Parent`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    int parentMember;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
};
```

Now, I have a class template for custom implementation of a dynamic array (unnecessary parts skipped)

```
template <typename T>
class DArray
{
private:
    T* m_array;
    int32_t m_length;
public:

    // Default constructor
    DArray() : m_array{ nullptr }, m_length{ 0 } {
    };

    // Search returns index of the first found item or -1 if not found, comparison is done 
    // using function pointer, which should return boolean
    int32_t Search(const T& data, bool(*comparisonFunction)(T, T)) {
        for (int32_t i = 0; i < m_length; i++) {
            if (comparisonFunction(m_array[i], data))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

I have a comparison function that will be used to find out if my dynamic array already contains an element with the same value of `parentMember`

```
bool comparisonFunction(Parent* n1, Parent* n2) {
    return (n1->parentMember == n2->parentMember);
}
```

Lastly, I have my dynamic array, which should hold pointers to `Child` objects.

```
int main()
{
    DArray<Child*> dArray;
    Child *c;
    dArray.Search(c, comparisonFunction);
    return 0;
}
```

This code returns error on this line:

```
dArray.Search(c, comparisonFunction);
```

The error is:

```
argument of type "bool (*)(Parent *n1, Parent *n2)" is incompatible with
parameter of type "bool (*)(Child *, Child *)"
```

My question is: Why doesn't the compiler implicitly convert `Child*` to `Parent*` as it does when I pass `Child*` as an argument to a function which takes `Parent*` as a parameter?

Is there any way how to solve this problem without implementing a new comparison function for every single child class?

Comment: any reason you don't use `std::vector` and `<algorithm>`?

Comment: @appleapple I'm still learning C++, and I want to understand how it works "behind the curtain" :)

Comment: Might be best to understand how to do it properly first.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit so how to do it properly then? What is not done properly in my code?

Comment: except for not using <vector> and <algorithm>?

Comment: That is what we are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler won't do this.

Generally it is best to submit functors as template parameters that way it will work with any item that could compile in that place. std::function and capturing lambda's for example would work with template arguments but not explicit function pointer declaration.

```
template <typename T>
class DArray
{
private:
    T* m_array;
    int32_t m_length;
public:

    // Default constructor
    DArray() : m_array{ nullptr }, m_length{ 0 } {
    };

    // Search returns index of the first found item or -1 if not found, comparison is done 
    // using function pointer, which should return boolean
    template<typename COMPARE>
    int32_t Search(const T& data,COMPARE& compareFunction) {
        for (int32_t i = 0; i < m_length; i++) {
            if (compareFunction(m_array[i], data))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There are no implicit conversions between pointer to function types.

I would change your `Search` function to a template function which can take any functor type (including lambdas, `std::function`, etc.).

```
template <typename F>
int32_t Search(const T& data, const F& comparisonFunction) {
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < m_length; i++) {
        if (comparisonFunction(m_array[i], data))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The implicit conversion from `Child *` to `Parent *` is not necessarily a no-op. It can involve pointer arithmetic and even conditionals (for checking null). So while it's possible to call a function expecting a `Parent *` with an argument of type `Child *`, it's only possible because the compiler will insert any necessary conversion code in the point of the call.

This means that while you can *convert* a `Child *` into a `Parent *`, you cannot *directly treat* a `Child *` as a `Parent *`. However, you algorithm uses a pointer to a function of type `bool(Child*, Child*)`. So it will pass two `Child *` objects into that function. At the site of the call through the function pointer, the compiler has no way of knowing that the pointer actually points to a `bool(Parent *, Parent*)` and that it should therefore insert conversion code from `Child *` to `Parent *` for each of the arguments.

No such code can be inserted at the site passing the pointer either. The compiler would effectively have to synthesise a wrapper of type `bool(Child *, Child *)`, put the conversion code into it, and pass a pointer to that wrapper into `Search`. That would be a bit too expensive for a single implicit conversion.

The correct solution to your problem has already been given by other answers: take inspiration from the standard `<algorithm>` header and accept an arbitrary functor instead of a function pointer:

```
template <class F>
int32_t Search(const T& data, F comparisonFunction) {
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < m_length; i++) {
        if (comparisonFunction(m_array[i], data))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation, I marked the answer that was first as correct.